# Unable to load AForge.Video.FFMPEG for ASP.NET application when it worked for a Windows Form application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, aforge

I am getting the following error:

> ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'AForge.Video.FFMPEG.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

I had this working in a Windows Forms project but after trying to convert the project to an ASP.NET one, I've been unable to get it to run. I was using a 64 bit DLL there, but have switched to using a 32 bit DLL now because I seem to be making more progress with that (got a similar error with the 64 bit DLL).

I've set the platform target to x86 in project properties and have also tried setting it to any CPU (which triggers warnings since the DLLs are native 32 bit) and have also tried changing the target to x64 while using the 64 bit DLLs.

In the IIS application pool, I have "Enable 32-Bit Applications" set to be true. Removing this one DLL causes the project to work and adding it back in causes it to fail.

I've tried:

1. Putting the DLLs in System32.
2. Putting the bin folder (with the DLLs) in the PATH.
3. Setting the application target to all possible choices (x86, x64, any CPU).
4. Verified the DLL is not corrupted and even tried one compiled by a different source.
5. All the FFMPEG DLLs are in the bin folder; also tried putting them in System32.

There's no code even using the DLLs in this project (I have code in a Windows Forms project that I'm going to merge into this, but I can't do that if the references don't even work). I've even created new projects in case there's some weird artefact in the projects.

Note that I've read pretty much every Google result related to this DLL and ASP.NET. None of the approaches seem to work.

Comment: Possibly of note is that I basically just used the default ASP.NET Web Forms application that VS 2013 generates, then removed all the stuff I didn't need and copied the Windows Forms application over, removing the Windows Forms stuff. There's no build errors or warnings.

Comment: I tried creating a blank ASP.NET application. I've used just the x86 DLLs this time and the moment I add the AForge,Video.FFMPEG DLL, I get an error that the assembly cannot be found. It no longer mentions an attempt to load a program with an incorrect format.

Comment: Visual Studio also gives a warning. It specifically mentions a page and puts that squiggly underline under the ASP.NET tag in that file, stating "Could not load file or assembly 'AForge.Video.FFMPEG.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found." This is weird because my code does not yet refer to this assembly and the moment I remove the assembly everything works. Of course, I need this assembly...

Comment: Perhaps also of note is that the DLL is viewable in the object browser. The path is correct and the object browser correctly shows the objects in the DLL. So it's not corrupted or anything and it seems to be visible.

Comment: Looking around the web, I found a mention that native DLLs would be loaded from System32 instead of the bin folder, so I copied all the DLLs there. No change. Didn't really expect it to considering that Visual Studio warns me (and VS at least should be aware of the assembly).

Comment: If anyone wants the project to test on or replicate this issue, the project files are [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B83OsFbbSQU3VTRqWExVcE1ORWM/view?usp=sharing). There's very little code. It pretty much just has the DLLs.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. Now it's working nice. I did couple of things. Though I am not sure which one was actually made my application working.

1. Copied DLLs from "Externals\ffmpeg\bin" to project's output directory (where executable stays);
2. Also copied those .dlls in C:/Windows/System32 directory.
3. Set built for x86 target (runs in 32-bit mode).
4. Though my project was based on framework 4.5, I also installed v3.5.
5. Finally, I added `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"` in app.config -

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <configuration>
>    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> //useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy for older .net version
>       <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
>    </startup>    
>  </configuration>
> ```

Comment: I assume it was step 3, because I keep finding forums where they say it's not compatible with x64, like [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/634e8fa7-0cf7-43a2-97d7-25087041649f/aforgevideoffmpeg-dll-error?forum=csharpgeneral). I'm not sure whether the rest made any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I've found *a* solution. For whatever reason, putting the FFmpeg DLLs (avformat-53.dll, avutil-51.dll, etc) in the `C:\Windows\System32` folder works.

I don't understand why the DLLs can't simply be in the PATH. Also, it's quite inconvenient to be placing DLLs in this location.

Due to how unideal this is, I'm going to hold off accepting this as the answer, in hopes that someone else can give a better solution or at least explain why the PATH or System32 did not work.

Comment: Hi Mike, any more developments since you wrote this?

Comment: @JamesMundy, actually, yes, but I don't consider my solution any better. It's less setup for the environment, but more work for the code. I "simply" loaded the native DLLs in my application in `Application_Start` (really any time before they're needed). This required calling Win32 code (using the `DllImport` attribute to get `LoadLibrary` from `Kernel32.dll`). Then the parts of my code that depend on the native DLLs must load that assembly dynamically (using the `Assembly` class). Which means every Aforge.FFmpeg method must be called via reflection. It's kinda ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that this error was resolved when I did the following steps (with AForge DLL's in your project and referenced):-

1. Right Click your Project --> Select Properties
2. Click Build (on the left)
3. Change Platform target to X86

See if this helps, it worked for me!

Comment: works for me . visual studio 2015, mvc web application.